# why is the value of $(-1)^\frac{2}{3}$ not 1?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots, irrational-numbers, cubics

$(-1)^2$ equals 1

also $(-1)^\frac{1}{3}$ equals -1

any way you arrange it, it should be one.

how ever, typing this into Wolfram or google,gives me an irrational complex number.

I would love some explaining on this.

thank you.

Comment: $(-1)^{1/3}\neq 1$, since $1^3\neq -1$.

Comment: yes, forgot the - , edited, thank you.

Comment: OK, so now one should let $(-1)^{1/3}$ denote one of three possible solutions to $z^3=-1$. Wolfram Alpha selects $\tfrac{1}{2}(1+i\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: The question is unclear since there is no way to canonically define a function $w$ on $\mathbb C$ such that $w(z)^3=z^2$ for every $z$. So what are you calling $z^{2/3}$ when $z=-1$?

Comment: Note that, this is the formal definition of the complex (or even real) power :
$$z^w:=\exp(w\log z)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha interprets $x^{1/3}$ as the *principal complex cubic root* of $x$, so $x^{2/3}$ is also a complex number. Despite of this, WA computes also the three complex roots (some rows below).

If we restrict ourselves to real numbers, an expression with a rational exponent as $a^{n/m}$ can be defined as $\left(\sqrt[m]{a}\right)^n$, where $\sqrt[m]{a}$ means the principal $m$-th root of $a$, then we have
\begin{align}
(-1)^{2/3}&=\left[(-1)^{1/3}\right]^2\\
&=(\sqrt[3]{-1})^2\\
&=(-1)^2\\
&=1
\end{align}

When we work with complex numbers $z^{1/n}$ is multivalued, which means that there are many complex numbers $w_k$ such that $w_k^n=z$.

Comment: "by definition of rational exponents, we have" Any source for such a "definition"?

Comment: What a bad, bad, bad idea... But thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Did: I edited the post in order to make it clearer.

Comment: Please repost the source you indicated in a comment now deleted.

Comment: @Did Not that bad an idea if one works in $\Bbb R$. $n$-th root is well defined for negative arguments, when $n$ is odd. You even have $a^pb^p=(ab)^p$, $a^{p+q}=a^pa^q$ and $(a^p)^q=a^{pq}$ for rational $p$ and $q$ with odd denominator and real $a,b$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Hmmm... Compare your optimistic take on this with the hoard of questions on the subject on m.se.

Comment: @Did Is *optimistic* a third [truth value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-valued_logic)?

Answer (score 2):

In general, when raising numbers to non-integer powers, there is not a unique answer in the complex numbers.  This is a generalization of the fact that numbers have two different square roots.  It turns out that when you raise a number $z$ to a rational power $m/n$, there are $n$ different complex numbers that can be considered "values" of $z^{m/n}$.  In this case, $n=3$, so there are actually $3$ different values of $(-1)^{2/3}$.  One of these values is indeed $1$, but the other two are complicated-looking complex numbers.  In general, there is no way to say which value is the "right" or "best" one, so Wolfram Alpha uses a somewhat arbitrary rule to pick one (called the "principal value"), and it turns out that the value of $(-1)^{2/3}$ that it picks is one of the complex values, not $1$.  However, if you scroll down on https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-1%29%5E%282%2F3%29, you will find that it does eventually list all three possible values (under the heading "All 3rd roots of $(-1)^2$).  At the top of that page, you also can click "Use the real-valued root instead" to change the rule that Wolfram Alpha uses to choose the value, so that it will choose a real value (if one exists).  Clicking on it shows that with this rule, Wolfram Alpha does say that $(-1)^{2/3}$ is $1$: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-1%29%5E%282%2F3%29&a=%5E_Real.

As for why there are these multiple values, that is a longer story, but I am sure there are many good explanations available online (perhaps on this very site).  To find such explanations, try searching for terms like "exponentiation of complex numbers".

Answer (score 0):

$(-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}\neq 1$. 
$(-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ are the cube roots of unity . Now I guess you can see why there is such an answer that WA gives